# MSSQL Replace specific character in a string after a certain character

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

So my problem is that I need to replace a Specific character in a string but not the first occurance of this character.
eg:-
the string in the column can look like any of the following forms:

```
1234,
ab_12,
ab_12_34,
ab_12_34_5,
abc_12,
abc_12_34,
abc_12_34_5,
```

the results I need would be

```
1234,
ab_12,
ab_12 34,
ab-12 34 5,
abc_12,
abc_12 34,
abc_12 34 5,
```

so basically every under score after the first is replaced with a space.
I have used the Replace function but can only figure out how to replace all the underscores.

Comment: Have you tried building clr regexp function? It's not that hard to build but is very useful to have.

Answer (score 0):

It will be ugly to write, but use CharIndex() to get the location of the first underscore, and then use the Replace() function on the substring following the first underscore, and concatenate that to the SubString() up to and including the first underscore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CHARINDEX` to determine if are at least two occurence of `_` in your `VARCHAR`. If this is the case, you can take the `LEFT` part of the string until the first `_` and then concatenate the remainder of the string after replacing the `_` characters:

```
  DECLARE   @test VARCHAR(50)= 'ab_12_34_5'

SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('_', @test, 0) > 0 AND CHARINDEX('_',@test, CHARINDEX('_', @test, 0) + 1) > 0
          THEN LEFT(@test, CHARINDEX('_', @test, CHARINDEX('_', @test, 0) + 1)- 1) + 
          REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@test, CHARINDEX('_', @test, CHARINDEX('_', @test, 0) + 1),LEN(@test)), '_', ' ')
          ELSE @test
       END
```

Answer (score 0):

one more answer with `charindex, substrubg & left` functions:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (val varchar(255));
INSERT INTO @t 
VALUES ('1234'),
    ('ab_12'),
    ('ab_12_34'),
    ('ab_12_34_5'),
    ('abc_12'),
    ('abc_12_34'),
    ('abc_12_34_5');

SELECT val
    ,(
        LEFT(val, CHARINDEX('_',val,1))
        + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(val, CHARINDEX('_',val, 1) + 1, LEN(val)), '_', ' ')
      ) as v2

FROM @t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will work, I've tested it with your sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp ( val VARCHAR(20) )

INSERT  INTO #Temp
        ( val )
VALUES  ( '1234,' ),
        ( 'ab_12,' ),
        ( 'ab_12_34,' ),
        ( 'ab_12_34_5,' ),
        ( 'abc_12,' ),
        ( 'abc_12_34,' ),
        ( 'abc_12_34_5,' )

SELECT  val ,
        CHARINDEX('_', val, 1) AS FirstChar ,
        LEN(val) AS Length ,
        LEFT(val, CHARINDEX('_', val, 1)) AS LeftPart ,
        REPLACE(SUBSTRING(val, 
                          CHARINDEX('_', val, 1) + 1, 
                          LEN(val) - CHARINDEX('_', val, 1)), '_', ' ') AS Remainder ,
        LEFT(val, CHARINDEX('_', val, 1)) 
      + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(val, 
                          CHARINDEX('_', val, 1) + 1, 
                          LEN(val)- CHARINDEX('_', val, 1)), '_', ' ') Formatted
FROM    #Temp

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers the first one i tried was Tanner's and it works perfectly.